# Looping through coin market cap

Tags: python, pandas, api, loops, coinmarketcap

Hey everyone I am trying to access the Coin Market Cap API and return the top 5000 slugs their price and there 24 hour change in volume. I want to save what is returned to a CSV file as well so I can add it to a data frame. I tried a few time to write a loop using the response variable but have had no luck.
Any help will be great!

```
from inspect import Parameter
from requests import Request, Session
import json

url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest' # Coinmarketcap API url

headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'API KEY'
    } 

parameter = {'slug':**, 'convert': 'USD' }

session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

response = session.get(url, params=parameter)

for parameter in response:
    print(parameter)

print(response)
```

Comment: "have had no luck" - be specific. _What exactly is going wrong_? And is your API key header really meant to be the string 'API KEY'?

Comment: No I took out my API KEY before I posted this.  And what I mean is I made a loop that that loops through the parameter "for parameter in response" and then prints the parameter (its the loop at the bottom of my code before the last print() command).  This is what I got back: b'{"status":{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:21:50.990Z","error_code":400,"error_message":"Invalid value for \\"slug\\": \\"all\\"","elapse'b'd":0,"credit_count":0,"notice":null}}'. What I need instead is the slugs, Market cap, and 24 hour volume.

Answer (score 1):

Try something as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

API_KEY = 'your_api_key_as_string'
url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'

HEADERS = {'Accepts': 'application/json',
           'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': API_KEY}

PARAMS = {'convert': 'USD',
          'limit': 5000}

resp = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=PARAMS)

def get_data(resp):
    data = json.loads(resp.content)['data']
    rows = list()

    # check appropriate keys, e.g.:
    # data[0].keys()
    # dict_keys(['..., 'slug', ..., 'quote'])

    # check keys for `quote`:
    # data[0]['quote'].keys() # always only 'USD'
    # data[0]['quote']['USD'].keys()
    # dict_keys([..., 'volume_24h', ..., 'market_cap', ..., 'last_updated'])
    
    for item in data:
        rows.append([
             item['slug'], 
             item['quote']['USD']['market_cap'],
             item['quote']['USD']['volume_24h'],
             item['quote']['USD']['last_updated']])

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        rows, columns=['slug','market_cap','volume_24h','last_updated'])

    # remove timezone from datetime64[ns, UTC] in `last_updated`
    df['last_updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df.last_updated).dt.tz_localize(None)
    df.index.name = 'id'
    return(df)

if resp.status_code == 200:
    df = get_data(resp)
    # write to csv
    df.to_csv('crypto_latests.csv')
else:
    # bad request, handle error
    print(resp.status_code)
```

Result:

```
print(df.head())

        slug    market_cap    volume_24h        last_updated
id                                                          
0    bitcoin  3.861454e+11  4.041023e+10 2022-09-15 09:45:00
1   ethereum  1.951680e+11  2.509653e+10 2022-09-15 09:45:00
2     tether  6.789316e+10  6.372894e+10 2022-09-15 09:45:00
3   usd-coin  5.075118e+10  7.255377e+09 2022-09-15 09:45:00
4        bnb  4.450807e+10  1.128343e+09 2022-09-15 09:45:00

print(df.shape)
# (5000, 4)
```